# Plotly : Adding legend to subplot

Tags: python, plotly, legend, subplot

I'm working with python and plotly, and I'm trying to add a legend to each of my subplots. Which is not working...

When I'm running the following code,

```
import plotly
import numpy as np

fig = plotly.subplots.make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1)

y = np.arange(0,10,1)

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(y=y,name="name1"), row=1,col=1)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(y=y**2,name="name2"), row=1,col=1)


fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(y=y,name="name3"), row=2,col=1)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(y=y**2,name="name4"), row=2,col=1)

fig.show()
```

This is what I get:

[image]

But I'd like to have something like this:

[image]

Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I looked into it, the legend for each subplot seems to correspond from [this information](https://community.plotly.com/t/associating-subplots-legends-with-each-subplot-and-formatting-subplot-titles/33786). You suggested annotations there as an alternative, so I added them to your code.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import numpy as np

fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1)

y = np.arange(0,10,1)

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(y=y,name="name1", legendgroup='1'), row=1,col=1)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(y=y**2,name="name2", legendgroup='1'), row=1,col=1)


fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(y=y,name="name3", legendgroup='2'), row=2,col=1)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(y=y**2,name="name4", legendgroup='2'), row=2,col=1)

for row in [1,2]:
    if row == 1:
        fig.add_annotation(dict(x=1.0, y=0.7, xref="paper", yref="paper", 
                                text='name %d' %row, showarrow=False))
        fig.add_annotation(dict(x=1.0, y=1.0, xref="paper", yref="paper", 
                                text='name %d' %(row+1), showarrow=False))
    else:
        fig.add_annotation(dict(x=1.0, y=0.05, xref="paper", yref="paper", 
                                text='name %d' %(row+1), showarrow=False))
        fig.add_annotation(dict(x=1.0, y=0.4, xref="paper", yref="paper", 
                                text='name %d' %(row+2), showarrow=False))
        
fig.update_layout(legend_tracegroupgap=50)

fig.show()
```

[image]

**Update: The code and graphs have been updated to reflect the introduction of group functionality in the legend.**

Comment: That's indeed a clever way to do it. No way the legend could be fully displayed in the subplots though?

Comment: As I commented, it seems you can't add a legend to the subplot at this time, as it's been exchanged in the plotly community.

Comment: I suggest also to see [this solution](https://www.kaggle.com/jrmistry/plotly-how-to-make-individual-legends-in-subplot) to emulate a legend for each subplot because I prefer it

Comment: is not Working, maybe you have another idea